# Convert by libreoffice to pdf error No such file or directory

Tags: c#, linux, pdf, libreoffice

```
fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), string.Concat(name, ".odt"));

using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
  inputStream.Position = 0;
  inputStream.CopyTo(fs);
  fs.Close();
}

progPath = @"/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice";
var args = string.Format("--headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), fileName);    
psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  FileName = progPath,
  Arguments = args
};
        
using(var p = Process.Start(psi))
{
  if(p != null)
  p.WaitForExit()
}
```

Code execute unde site. In log error No such file or directory. If output Environment.UserName it is root.
File.Exists(fileName) passed as true. But File.Exists(progPath) is false.

Tried this code

```
psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  FileName = "/bin/bash",
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  Arguments = string.Format("-c \"sudo {0} {1}\"", progPath, args)
};
```

no errors, but no pdf file (File.Exists() is false)

read similar problem - no issue helped

Comment: What happens if you run this from the shell directly?

Comment: You don't have to start a shell to run another application. The shell is only used to issue shell commands.

Comment: `But File.Exists(progPath) is false.` in that case how do you expect to run a non-existent propgram? What's the actual location of the Libre executable? Try `which soffice` to find it

Comment: From shel all fine. File converted.

File exists
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program$ ls -al soffice
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6738 May 25 23:52 soffice

Comment: One strange thing, when FileStream save file, File.Exist is true, but not see file in /tmp